# How to use a postProcess with i18next?

Tags: react-native, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

From [this article](https://i18next.github.io/i18next/pages/doc_features.html) I read that you can add a post processing function to `i18next`:

```
i18n.addPostProcessor("myProcessorsName", function(value, key, options) 
{
   return 'some post processed data based on translated value';
});
```

and add it during initialization:

```
i18n.init({ postProcess: 'myProcessorsName' });
```

But I get an error `addPostProcessor` is not a function.

So how can I add and use a post processing function to `i18next`?

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation](https://www.i18next.com/misc/creating-own-plugins) I figured you can create a post process module and add it to the `i18next` instance with `use()`.

In this example, the post process module will capitalize the first letter of any string returned:

```
import i18next from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

(...)

const CapitalizeFirstLetter = (str) => {
  return str.length ? str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1) : str
}

const initTranslations = () => {
    i18next
    .use({
      type: 'postProcessor',
      name: 'capitalize',
      process: function (value, key, options, translator) {
        return CapitalizeFirstLetter(value);
      }
    })
    .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
    .init({
      postProcess: ["capitalize"]
    })
}
```